# How do I simplify this Enumerator code?

Tags: ruby, optimization, enumerator, simplification

I'd like to optimize following code for conciseness.

```
x1.each { |x| 
  x2.each { |y|
    ....
    xN.each { |z|
      yield {}.merge(x).merge(y)...... merge(z)
    }
  }
}
```

Assume `x1, x2, ..., xN` are [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html) objects.

1. The above is not concise
2. It works with x1, x2 as `Array`s, but not as `Enumerator`s

   - Because enumerator iterators should be reset for inner loops

I tried this but without success:

```
[x1, x2, ..., xN].reduce(:product).map { |x| x.reduce :merge }
```

Any recommendations?

**UPDATE**

currently solved with:

```
[x1, x2, ..., xN].map(:to_a).reduce(:product).map { |x| 
  yield x.flatten.reduce(:merge) 
}
```

Comment: optimize as in performance or as in conciseness?

Comment: `x1.product(x2,.,xn).each { |hash,elem| elem.reduce({},:merge) }` may work...

Comment: 1. conciseness
2. this works with x1, x2 as Array, but not with enumerators, because for inner loops enumerator iterators should be reseted. I tried this but without success:

`[x1, x2, ..., xN].reduce(:product).map { |x| x.reduce :merge }`

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: `product` is not defined on `Enumerator` instances.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - You need to call to_a first, however this will not work with all enumerators

Answer (score 5):

I'll start with point #2:

- At least with the `Enumerators` I've tested (`[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}].each`) your code worked - apparently `Enumerator#each` either rewinds at the end, or it uses its own pointer.
- To do what you want, you need to iterate so many times over the `Enumerator` objects (especially the inner ones) that calling `to_a` on each at first will not increase your time complexity at all (it will stay `O(n1*n2*...*nk)`

With point #1, if calling `to_a` is out of the question, you can consider recursion:

```
def deep_merge(enum = nil, *enums)
  if enum.nil?
    yield({})
  else
    enum.each do |x|
      deep_merge(*enums) do |h|
        yield h.merge(x)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

now you can call `deep_merge(x1, x2, ... xN)` and get the needed outcome...

Comment: Even if OP can work with `.to_a`, I think that any structure that (like this answer) avoids creating a giant product is a good result. You can iterate 10 million items reasonably fast, but holding 10 million hashes in memory in order to do so could impact performance.